# Mongoose nodejs - authentication failed trying to connect to mongodb docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb container using mongoose. This is my `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  mongonet:

services:
  mongodatabase:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodatabase
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - mongonet
  mongojs:
    depends_on:
      mongodatabase:
        condition: service_started
    container_name: mongojs
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodatabase:27017/test
    networks:
      - mongonet
```

Containers start and work ok, but problems appear when using mongoose:

```
const mongoose = requrie('mongoose')
const {MONGO_URI} = require('./../config/env')


exports.__mongo_ini = async function () {
  const connectOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, connectOptions)
    console.info(`===> Connected to database ${MONGO_URI}`)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.warn(`===> Couldn't connect: ${err}`)
  }
}
```

When using the env URI `mongodb://mongodatabase:27017/test` It says connected. But then If I try to find a model:

```
await models.Star.find().catch(r => r)
```

I get the error:

```
MongoServerError: command find requires authentication
at Connection.onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:203:30)
at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:60)
....
ok: 0,
code: 13,
codeName: 'Unauthorized',
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

My model:

```
const starSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    starName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    },
    designation: {
        type: String
    },
    constelation: {
        type: String
    },
    named: {
        type: Date
    },
    timeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})

const Star = mongoose.model('Star',starSchema)

module.exports = Star
```

Tried to add a mongo entrypoint volume in my docker compose:

```
volumes:
      - ./mongo-entrypoint/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

Mongo-init.js:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({
    user: 'testuser',
    pwd: 'testpass',
    roles: [
        {
            role: 'readWrite',
            db: 'test'
        }
    ]
})
db.getSiblingDB('test').createCollection('collection_test');
```

So I try to connect changing the mongo uri to use user and password:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://testuser:testpass@mongodatabase:27017/test
```

But It says authentication failed when trying to connect to the mongo uri and the mongo entrypoint doesn't seem to run:

```
Couldn't connect: MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

I've tried so many things and none of them work. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in node js

database.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log("MongoDB connection SUCCESS");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("MongoDB connection FAIL");
  }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

.env

```
MONGO_URI=your_mongodb_url
```

Create a models file
models.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const CategorysSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      description: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      publishedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    });
    
 module.exports = mongoose.model("categorys_collection", CategorysSchema);
```

Find Models

```
const Category_Model = require("./models");
    app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const Category = await Category_Model.find();
        res.json(Category);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message, status: "error" });
      }
    });
```

Comment: My nodejs code is actually the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @HarshSingh The problem doesn't rely on my nodejs code. I'm able to connect when using the URI: `mongodb://mongodatabase:27017/test`, but then If I try to find in a model I get the error `MongoServerError: command find requires authentication`. Tried using the URI: `mongodb://admin:admin@mongodatabase:27017/test`  I get the error `MongoServerError: Authentication failed` when trying to connect, as I said in my question.

Comment: You need to create a schema to find the model

Comment: I have given an answer please check again

Comment: @HarshSingh I already have a model. See my update. Also note that i'm not using express.